# Passing values in view block to contextual filter on Panelized Node

Tags: views, 8, panels

I have a view set up with a contextual filter for year (select list field).  I want to have the ability to have one view and pass the year to the view.

Now I have panelized nodes that I add the views to and I want to pass different years to each view.   In Drupal 7 I used to be able to do this with View Panes.  Is this not possible in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch that may add this functonality: [How to manually pass an argument to a views block through interface](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/issues/2759445).